# My default page is in php and I will the html and the php

Tags: php, html, default

I am a young developper (15 year)
I have a problem white my website. My page does not synchronize with html and php in "localhost/sn/".  Normally when I type "localhost/sn/" in my browser I should have the html page synchronized with the php. But it doesn't work. When I type that, I only have my index.php page.
my server is with XAMPP.
Please help me!!!!!

Comment: Hi. Your question is unclear. Please explain what do you mean by "not synchronize"? Show us part of the code where you problem.

Comment: I normally need to have the html page with the PHP function as default page.

Comment: What does "synchronize" means? You can have an init index.php OR index.html per directory. Not both. I think the directory "sn"  contains index.html and index.php and you are wondering why only the .php is loaded.

Comment: Yes, that is it

Comment: Web servers choose index.php first, and if there is not, it chooses index.html. A web server can not load 2 files/pages at the same time/url.

Comment: It’s not a web server, it’s a local host

Comment: Just because you are using the host name `localhost` to access this in your browser, does not mean that there is no web server running - it is a *local* web server. You seem to be confused about a lot of the common terminology here, which makes it harder to help you … because what you actual problem is, is still rather unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run your website with only html and css structures, you use the file with the extension html (e.x index.html) and of course you do not need to use XAMPP.

If you want to run your website and have php code then use the file with the extension php (e.x index.php) and more importantly you need to put it in the htdocs directory of XAMPP.

Comment: Okay, but I need the index.php with my html template.

Comment: You can freely put your html and css code into php file, just the opposite can't put php code and html file

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can do.

First, PHP is a programming language, where you can mix PHP code and HTML output together. There are several reasons, why you shouldn't (so called spaghetti code, see [here](http://thisinterestsme.com/mixing-php-html/)), but as you are just starting, this seems to be ok.
On the other hand, you can integrate your HTML into your PHP with [`require`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.require.php) or [`include`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.include.php).

Of course you are not bount to either the one ore the other. You can mix the two approaches (and every serious PHP app does it)

### Mixing HTML and PHP

```
<?php
// We are in PHP country now

// Set the value of variable
$header = "My 1st header";
// This ends PHP country
?>
<!-- Now we are in HTML country -->
<h1><?= $header =></h1>
<?php
// PHP country again
// the character string `<?&= some_value ?>;` 
// is a shortcut for `<?php echo some_value; ?>`
$count = 4;
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo "<p>Paragraph</p>";
}
```

This will output `<h1>My 1st header</h><p>Paragraph</p><p>Paragraph</p><p>Paragraph</p><p>Paragraph</p>`

### Include HTML in PHP

Here we have two files

#### index.php:

```
<?php 
require "header.html";

echo "<p>Content</p>";
```

#### header.html

```
<h1>My 2nd header</h1>
```

Calling index.php in XAMPP will yield `<h1>My 2nd header</h1><p>Content</p>`

Comment: Thank you, but can I ask you questions in private

Answer (score 0):

You only need 1 file {index.php},

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <?php 
    echo ("Hello Arthur!"); 
    ?>
      </head>
      <body>

        <div id="top">
            asdfasdfsd
            <div id="under">
            asdfsadf
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- page content -->
      </body>
    </html>
```

then, open Chrome or whatever browser you like, type: 
*localhost/index.php*

make sure the {index.php} file is in htdocs folder and xampp Apache is turned on.

hope I helped.

Comment: You shouldn't output anything before the DOCTYPE declaration (`<!DOCTYPE html>`)

Answer (score -1):

if you want just show html page then u do not need xampp. If you want to show html page with some logic then it have to be index.php with template in html

Comment: Okay and how can I do the second option?